# Wordpress Giving Random 404 on Custom Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I've got a site that is giving intermittent (but rare) 404 errors for pages that trigger a custom rewrite written in Wordpress. The pretty URL will work most of the time and a refresh of the page will make it load correctly if it does 404.

Links have been rewritten using the following function:

```
function my_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 )
{               
    $type = $post->post_type;
    switch( $type ) 
    {
        case 'sfwd-courses':    //Change Courses links to Modules
           return home_url( 'module/' . $post->ID . '/' . $post->post_name );
        case 'sfwd-lessons':    //Change Lessons links to Focuses
           return home_url( 'focus/' . $post->ID . '/' . $post->post_name );
        case 'sfwd-topic':      //Change Topics links to Lessons
           return home_url( 'lesson/' . $post->ID . '/' . $post->post_name );
        case 'my_course':      
           return home_url( 'course/' . $post->ID . '/' . $post->post_name );
        default:
            return $link; 
    }
}
```

This works as expected.

I then rewrite these new links with:

```
function my_rewrites_init()
{           
    flush_rewrite_rules();
    add_rewrite_rule('module/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)?$', 'index.php?post_type=sfwd-courses&p=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]' , 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('focus/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)?$', 'index.php?post_type=sfwd-lessons&p=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]' , 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('lesson/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)?$', 'index.php?post_type=sfwd-topic&p=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]' , 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('course/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)?$', 'index.php?post_type=aha_course&p=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]' , 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrites_init');
```

Server logs that I have seen so far just report the 404 on the rewritten link but visiting the failed link will work.

I'm not sure if I have missed something in the rewrite function or if the problem could be elsewhere.  Permalinks have been recreated but still getting the random 404.

I have only triggered the 404 once on my local WAMP dev server but the production server is doing it more often.  The product server is IIS.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not yet configured your web.config for IIS, do so adding this code:
UPDATE:

```
   <rewrite>
      <rules><rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true"><match url=".*"/><conditions><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/></conditions><action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page_id={R:0}"/></rule>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Also, if you are using any non-latin symbols in your pretty links (article titles), add to you wp-config.php this code:

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL']) ) {
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'];
}
```

Comment: Hi Vladislav, there are no non-latin symbols in the article titles.  You IIS config settings didn't come though.